# Как определить, что результат не попал в выборку

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Есть некий тестируемый метод репозитория, который выбирает какие-то данные по условию.
Как определить, что в выборку не попал ненужный результат?
На данный момент используются фикстуры и для того, чтобы проверить, что в выборке нет ненужного свойства, перебирается массив с результатами и проверяется, что в массиве нет этого значения.
Пример

```
$subject = $this->getByReference('subj');  
$unnecessaryProp = $this->getByReference('u-prop');
$result = $this->em->getRepository('Repo')->findPropsBySubject($subject);
foreach($result as $prop)
{
  $this->assertNotSame($unnecessaryProp->getId(), $prop->getId(), 'Error text...');
}
```

Как это можно сделать более лаконично/правильно, чтобы не перебирать массив?

Comment: Вероятно, можно просто пройтись по массиву, как только найден неподходящий элемент - поставить какой-то флаг и прервать цикл. Далее проверить что флаг установлен/не установлен.

Comment: @u_mulder , зачем? Если найдётся ненужный элемент тест будет завален, цикл прервётся.
Вопрос в том, можно ли  это сделать по-другому? М.б. в PHPUnit есть какие-то фичи, которых я не нашёл

Comment: Просто в итоге в моем случае один assert, а у вас столько сколько элементов в цикле.

Comment: Но в целом, если у вас заданы какие-то определенные фикстуры и вы знаете сколько элементов вернется в результате запроса, то можно проверить число возвращаемых элементов и эталонное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать функцию  [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) для того, чтобы задать сложное условие проверки, или использовать [in_array](http://php.net/manual/function.in-array.php) для проверки вхождения одиночного значения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно применить array_reduce на полученном массиве

```
$subject = $this->getByReference('subj');  
$unnecessaryProp = $this->getByReference('u-prop');
$result = $this->em->getRepository('Repo')->findPropsBySubject($subject);

// Id, которого не должно быть в результате
$unnecessaryId = $unnecessaryProp->getId();

// Если $unnecessaryId присутствует в массиве, то $checkResult вернет true, иначе false
$checkResult = array_reduce(function($carry, $item) use ($unnecessaryId) {
    return $carry || $item->getId() === $unnecessaryId;
}, false);

// Проверяем $checkResult на false
$this->assertFalse($checkResult, 'Ooops unnecessary id in array');
```